# Develop nodejs with Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Microsoft has announced the new cross platform IDE [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I don't see how can enable nodejs tools for it. As far as I understand there should be something coming out of the box.

Comment: There seems to be [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs) ?

Answer (score 2):

Node.js tools are automatically enabled. In order to activate them, you need to:

1. Hover your mouse over Node specific code (such as a `require` statement)
2. Click on the lightbulb
3. Select the option that contains the `Add /// reference to 'node/node.d.ts'` construct
4. That's it

It doesn't matter where you put the `reference` string.